# Skype call default to share my screen automatically?

Tags: skype, automation

I often call my teamates and share my screen. Is there a setting that allow me to **share my screen** as my voice call start **automatically**?

I'm using Skype on Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about voice call start, but you can do video call and screen sharing at the same time. Follow these steps:

Go to `Settings > options` and in `'Incoming video and screen sharing'` > select`"Start Automatically"`.

Comment: Can you take snapshot where that setting is?

Comment: I can't find it in my Skype setting.

Comment: this setting is available in Windows 8.1 Skype built-in app. if you are using manually downloaded app then, create a group and share screen to that particular group.

Comment: I'm using I'm using `Skype on Windows 7`